# Swashbuckle complex objects members decoration

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I'm having trouble to find how to mark required members of complex objects I use as parameters for my actions using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (latest version available through nuGet package manager) in a .NET Core WebAPI project.

I have implemented a custom `IOperationFilter` that adds a `required = true` flag for the action parameters but obviously it does not go through the complex objects definition so all their members are still marked as optional.

What I would like to obtain is this:

```
definitions:   
  ComplexObjectParameters:
    description: 'my complex object parameter'
    type: object
    required: ['parameter1', 'parameter2']
    properties:
      parameter1:
        type: string
      parameter2:
        type: string
      parameter3:
        type: string
```

Do you have any idea how I could implement this?

EDIT: a demo project demonstrating my issue is available here: https://github.com/albator1932/ComplexObjects

Comment: Troubleshooting something like this is very difficult without the full picture...
Can you create a simple project on GitHub that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Yes, of course, here it is: https://github.com/albator1932/ComplexObjects

Running the project and going to /swagger/ URL will show the input parameter marked as required (which is good) but all the members are marked as optional (and some for the response).

Comment: I sent you a pull request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an **IDocumentFilter** and add **[Required]** to the fields that are required:

```
internal class AddComplexObjectRequiredParameter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        if (swaggerDoc.Definitions != null)
        {
            if (swaggerDoc.Definitions["ComplexObjectParameters"].Required == null)
                swaggerDoc.Definitions["ComplexObjectParameters"].Required = new List<string>();
            foreach (var field in typeof(ComplexObjectParameters).GetFields())
            {
                if (Attribute.IsDefined(field, typeof(RequiredAttribute)))
                    swaggerDoc.Definitions["ComplexObjectParameters"].Required.Add(field.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! 
However that's not exactly how I wanted to achieve this: I have quite a lot of objects and some have many properties so listing them like this is tedious to say the least.
Is there any way to create some kind of decoration that I could add to the object properties instead ?

Comment: The decorator [Required] is the way to go, that should work! but there is a bug in swashbuckle that breaks it.

Comment: I just made an edit to my suggestion to not hardcode the members, it should no longer be a tedious task...